# jQuery - Get div child's src by class

Tags: jquery, children, src

I have the following jsfiddle which shows and hides various groups of images based on a users selected options. This works correctly but I need to be able to also put the src of one of these images into an input box. Code and fiddle below.

When the select box changes how can i go about getting one of the visible images src into my `image_text` input field? I was hoping to use the `child()` method but this doesn't work:

```
jQuery("#image_text").val( jQuery("div[class*='"+choice_opt+"']").child().props("src") );
```

**CODE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/WMyc7/2/

**jquery:**

```
function setImages() {
    jQuery(".image_holder").css("display", "none");
    var abt = jQuery("#select_About option:selected").text();
    jQuery("div[class*='" + abt + "']").css("display", "block");
}

jQuery('select').on('change', function () {
    setImages();
});

setImages();
```

**html:**

```
<div>
<div class="image_holder Animals">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image_holder Animals">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-8.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image_holder Places To Go">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-100-100-9.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image_holder Places To Go">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image_holder Misc Items">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-100-100-1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image_holder Misc Items">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

<h1>Select</h1>
<select id="select_About">
    <option value="0">Animals</option>
    <option value="1">Places To Go</option>
    <option value="2">Misc Items</option>
</select>

<h1>SRC</h1>
<input type="text" name="image" id="image_text">
```

Comment: ***one of the visible images src*** so what is the exact one you want to show its src?

Comment: @KingKing it can be any image just needs to be one of the currently visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like that :

```
function setImages() {
    jQuery(".image_holder").css("display", "none");
    var abt = jQuery("#select_About option:selected").text();
    jQuery("div[class*='" + abt + "']").css("display", "block");
    $("[name=image]").attr("value",(jQuery("div[class*='" + abt +"']").find("img").attr("src")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I add in that code it just shows as [object Object] as here: http://jsfiddle.net/WMyc7/5/

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WMyc7/7/

Sorry, but I couldn't help refactoring your function a little bit to what IMO is a way more performant and maintainable approach. I also changed your `SELECT`'s options to values that made the code a lot easier. Btw, it's best practice to only use lower case for classes and IDs.

The changed HTML:

```
<select id="select_About">
  <option value="animals">Animals</option>
  <option value="places_to_go">Places To Go</option>
  <option value="misc_items">Misc Items</option>
</select>
```

And the JS:

```
jQuery(function(){

    // DOM READY

    // Cache everything that is needed frequently
    var $imageHolders = jQuery(".image_holder"),
        $srcInput = jQuery('#image_text');

    function setImages() {
        var abt = jQuery("#select_About").val(),
            // Filter image holders by class selected
            $visibleImages = $imageHolders.filter('.'+ abt),
            src;

        // Hide all images
        $imageHolders.hide();
        // Show all images filtered by class in select dropdown
        $visibleImages.show();
        // Get src attribute of first image (attr always gets first of an array of elements)
        src = $visibleImages.find('img').attr('src');
        // set input field to src value
        $srcInput.val( src )
    }

    jQuery('select').on('change', function () {
        setImages();
    });

    setImages();

});
```